# CUDA thrust device pointer with transform copy crash

Tags: cuda, thrust

In CUDA 9.2 I have something like this:

```
#ifdef __CUDA_ARCH__
    struct Context { float n[4]; } context;
#else
    typedef __m128 Context;
#endif
struct A { float k[2]; };
struct B { float q[4]; };


struct FTransform : thrust::unary_function<A, B>
{
    const Context context;


    FTransform(Context context) : context(context){}


    __device__ __host__ B operator()(const A& a) const
    {
        B b{{a.k[0], a.k[1], a.k[0]*context.n[0], a.k[1]*context.n[1]}};



        return b;
    }
};


void DoThrust(B* _bs, const Context& context, A* _as, uint32_t count)
{
    thrust::device_ptr<B> bs = thrust::device_pointer_cast(_bs);
    thrust::device_ptr<A> as = thrust::device_pointer_cast(_as);

    FTransform fTransform(context);

    auto first = thrust::make_transform_iterator(as, fTransform);
    auto last = thrust::make_transform_iterator(as + count, fTransform);


    thrust::copy(first, last, bs);
}


int main(int c, char **argv)
{
    const uint32_t Count = 4;
    Context context;

    A* as;
    B* bs;

    cudaMalloc(&as, Count*sizeof(A));
    cudaMalloc(&bs, Count*sizeof(B));

    A hostAs[Count];
    cudaMemcpy(as, hostAs, Count * sizeof(A), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);


    DoThrust(bs, context, as, Count);


        B hostBs[Count];
        cudaMemcpy(hostBs, bs, Count * sizeof(B), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);//crash

return 0;
    }
```

Then when I call a standard cudaMemcpy() call later on the results I get the exception "an illegal memory access was encountered".

If I replace the thrust code with a non-thrust equivalent there is no error and everything works fine.  Various combinations of trying to copy to device_vectors etc I get different crashes that seem to be thrust trying to release the device_ptr's for some reason - so maybe it is here for some reason?

== UPDATE ==

Ok that was confusing it appears it's due to the functor FTransform context member variable in my actual more complicated case.  This specifically:

```
struct FTransform : thrust::unary_function<A, B>
{
    #ifdef __CUDA_ARCH__
        struct Context { float v[4]; } context;
    #else
        __m128 context;
    #endif
    ...
};
```

So I guess it's an alignment problem somehow => in fact it is, as this works:

```
#ifdef __CUDA_ARCH__
    struct __align__(16) Context { float v[4]; } context;
#else
    __m128 context;
#endif
```

Comment: If you want help debugging a runtime error, then a [MCVE] is pretty much mandatory. Nothing you hypothesize in your question can occur and the problem is very likely in code you haven't even bothered to show.

Comment: I've updated the code.  But from your comment I can infer it looks like there should be no issue in the DoThrust() function and I am not misunderstanding how thrusts device_ptrs are supposed to work?  Perhaps there is problem with the functor then?

Comment: By visual inspection, the code you added won't compile. Did you bother to,compile and run it and confirm that it produces the behaviour you are complaning about?

Comment: Midway through writing it I found that simple test case works it seems and must have hit submit  (I just edited so at least that simple case compiles without error now) while I have been trying to dig deeper to try ascertain the difference between the test case and the actual more complicated version.  At least I know from your first helpful comment that my intended usage of thrust device pointers appears correct, so the problem would appear to not be there.  I'm really not quite sure at all what is going on here.

Comment: It appears it's something to do in my complicated case (that is difficult to extract into a simple example currently given all the extra code it relies on - but I am trying!), that it's something to do with the member variables 'context' in the FTransform functor.

Comment: Ok that was confusing... I have narrowed it down to a problem if the context contains an SSE __m128 member - the exact struct used is defining a __m128 in the CPU build pass but a float[4] in the GPU CUDA build pass, but layout wise they should be compatible.  Still digging more, but sorry that wasn't very obvious and I wasn't sure if understood thrust device ptrs properly hence my train of original thought...

Comment: I've updated the end of the question regards the actual problem now.

Comment: So once again we are back in the situation where there is no [MCVE]. I am guessing you have actually done something illegal/broken in your functor, but you haven't shown the relevant code....

Comment: It was an accidentally inconsistently defined alignment between a type that was defined differently between NVCC compiler passes causing confusing bad things to happen.  Question and answer now updated as it's a good gotcha for others to be aware of.

Answer (score -2):

The solution is to ensure that if you use aligned types in thrust functor members (such as __m128 SSE types) that are copied to the GPU, that they are defined as aligned both during NVCC's CPU and GPU code build passes - and not accidentally assume even if a type may seem to naturally align to it's equivalent in the other pass that it will be ok, as otherwise bad hard to understand things may happen.

So for example the _ *align* _(16) is necessary in code like this:

```
struct FTransform : thrust::unary_function<A, B>
{
#ifdef __CUDA_ARCH__
    struct __align__(16) Context { float v[4]; } context;
#else
    __m128 context;
#endif


    FTransform(Context context) : context(context){}
    __device__ __host__ B operator()(const A& a) const; // function makes use of context
};
```

Comment: There are (I suspect) a number dodgy implementation details which you have left out of your description of the functor which are the actual cause of the error and which you are masking by playing with alignment. At some point, the code you have shown will attempt to compile to [this](https://pastebin.com/ZfNZjycG) and should fail. So there is likely some undefined behaviour you are relying on which accidentally works. But don't rely on that always being the case.